# How to restore Ubuntu18.04 network kernel parameter?

Tags: networking, kernel

I messed up the kernel parameters and now no services except SSH could be started, does anybody know how to restore those network or kernel parameter? I don't want to re-install the system, Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can we know what method use used to disable or remove the kernel parameters.  Did you disable it via a grub change, package removal, disable services or other. Look at your `history` would be what I would do first, then looking at logs (eg. apt) to see what (if anything) you removed; or if you have a clue on when, looking for files modified in that period etc. When you make a change, don't you leave breadcrumbs for yourself in case something doesn't work as expected?  I'd check those notes.

Comment: i changed them via sysctl and sysctl.conf before, and then .bash_history was cleared afterwards. but then i found that some services were not able to be started. my question is is there any methods to restore these kernel parameters as they were right after the system was installed. i didn't change any configurations in grub and it's nothing to do with package removing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify which parameters you changed in sysctl.conf, it makes it somewhat difficult, but here's the basic method...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
  - `sudo pico /etc/sysctl.conf`
  - restore the values that you changed
  - if you need the default values, tell us which parameters you changed
  - save the file
  - `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Reinstalled Ubuntu. Sysctl.conf restored. System is fully operational.

Comment: thanks! but i did forget what parameters i changed, and actually i used sysctl -w method to change some kernel parameters. now i just wonder would i get some new default kernel parameters if i upgrade the kernel ...

Comment: @wrl no, you won't get a new sysctl.conf file with just a new kernel, but you probably will if you upgrade to 18.10. You might see if you can get a virgin sysctl.conf from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Lesson learned... always backup sysctl.conf before making such massive and damaging changes...

Comment: @wrl status please...

Comment: unsolved, i'm checking all kernel parameters now, up to 900+...

Comment: @wrl Why don't you just reinstall 18.04, or upgrade to 18.10?

Comment: well, i finally re-installed the system, and found there were about 1200 kernel parameters right after the system was installed

Comment: @wrl great news! i updated the question. Please accept it if you can. Thanks!

Comment: done. actually, for this question, the best way is to save the output of "sysctl -a" from time to time, otherwise, it's no perfect solution to solve it at all, because every machine has different hardware and software installed, no two identical machines exist  on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your best chance is to install a fresh copy of /etc/sysctl.conf

You should be able to dig that out somehow from the distribution.
When you have a copy of this file, then you need to copy it.  THe easy way would be a USB stick, but maybe your system is too damaged to do that ?  If so, you could make a bootable USB stick with the copy and mount the file systems of your damaged system and copy the file.  I have in the past used the refind boot manager to do something  like this.  Once booted from the refind usb you need to do some chrooting and manual mounting to get to your system partitions.  But it is doable.  If you go down that path then I probably have written down the procedure somewhere for my own use if needed.

https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

If you dont want to use refind, there are other ways to make a bootable ubuntu usb - e.g.. :
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Comment: actually i did this to recovery the sysctl.conf "apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" -y install --reinstall procps", but then i realized that not all kernel parameters worte in the file. so something i changed by "sysctl -w" and "sysctl -p" cannot be reset by restoring the sysctl.conf. so now the question is how to fine tune all of the kernel parameters. what a terrible task ~

Comment: hmm.  This is chinese to me.   Could you please explain the relevance to my problem ?